# How to remove line breaks when using Regex Pattern.compile

Tags: java, android, arrays, regex

I'm trying to extract some information from HTML that is surrounded by tags on the line above and the line below. When I run the regex pattern.compile the end result returns the string I want, but also the white space before and after, which I don't want.

Can anyone help me find a way to get rid of the line breaks and return an Array of just string seperated by ", "?

**Here's my HTML:**

```
<div class="name">
                        Jonna Lundell
                    </div>
```

**Here's my Java code:**
Where result is the string of HTML text.

```
html = result;

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<div class=\"name\">(.+?)</div>", Pattern.DOTALL);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(html);

    while (m.find()) {
        nameList.add(m.group(1));}

Log.i("Names ", String.valueOf(nameList));
```

**Which returns:**

```
I/Names: [
                            Name 1
                        , 
                            Name 2
                        , 
                            Name 3
                        , 
                            Name 4
                        , 
                            Name 5
                        , 
                            Name 6
                        ]
```

Comment: `m.group(1)` => `m.group(1).trim()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the trim() method:

```
while (m.find()) {
    nameList.add(m.group(1).trim());
}
```